# Why does Fat Free framework use it's own variable instead of PHP?

Tags: php, variables, fat-free-framework

In PHP we can declare and edit variables like that,

```
$var = 1;
echo $var;
```

But PHP Fat-Free Framework has an option to declare a variable like that,

```
$f3->set('var', 13); //13 is a value
```

So my question is why it is used. There must should be a reason for making its own variable system. So what's the actuall reason? Isn't there any reason? Please someone help me because I am a newbie here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That framework has this as a way to globally store variables without polluting the global scope itself, and while remaining bound to the instance of your app. This way, you can set and retrieve variables from the framework assuming you have a reference to the framework root object.

This is **not** meant to replace every variable, merely the ones you want globally available across your entire code.

Comment: Thank you, is this like session?

Comment: @MdAshrafulIslam A session persists across page views for a given visitor, so no, different scope. This kind of variable resides until the end of execution, but no further than that.